# ConnectionJ - "Unable to access jarfile"

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I'm trying to access my mySQL database from my java program in intelliJ. I have used the correct database information as the Database Navigator plugin can connect fine. But I'm following a tutorial (https://youtu.be/e8g9eNnFpHQ) to use the Connector J jarfile and add it to my modules dependencies but I keep getting

> Error: Unable to access jarfile

Cant seem to get it to work.

I've tried to go to the properties of the jarfile and change the default opening app and that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to check your jarfile path
Like this :  java -jar D:\Java\IdeaProjects\springboot3\target\springboot3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score -1):

jarfile need to use an absolute path,